# Particle system unity not always showing, unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

So I'm trying to add a particle effect to a little space game of mine, I get axis "Vertical", then check if it is greater than 0 the particle system plays (going forward)

```
flyfloat = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
if(flyfloat > 0)
{
     particles.Play();
}
else
{
     particles.Stop();
}
```

That controls whether it is playing the particle system, but the issue i have is that it only gives some particles and then stops, I've viewed the `flyfloat` and it is at 1.

What may the problem be here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is incomplete as for example I don't know where you are using these lines of code.. inside an `Update()` method or a `Start()` method.

Assuming you are calling it in `Update()` method. Let me explain first what is happening wrong here. So as `Update()` gets called each frame when you pressing **UP_Arrow** key `flyfloat = 1` . that's ok but now as you go inside the if loop to check `flyfloat > 0` and calls `partciles.Play()` it is being called every `Update()` loop means every frame so what's happening is your `ParticleSystem` is getting played every frame so not playing at all. Also whenever you stops pressing the **UP_Arrow** key the `flyfloat = 0` for which it's going inside the else loop and stops playing the `ParticleSystem`.

So to solve this you can introduce a Boolean which makes `partciles.Play()` and `partciles.Stop()` gets called once when you are pressing **UP_Arrow** key.

below code will make the `ParticleSystem` play when you press **UP_Arrow** key and stops it when you press **DOWN_Arrow** key

```
    public ParticleSystem particles;
    public float flyfloat;

    bool isParticlePlaying = false;


    private void Update()
    {
        flyfloat = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (flyfloat > 0  && !isParticlePlaying)
        {
            particles.Play();
            isParticlePlaying = true;
        }
        else if (flyfloat < 0 && isParticlePlaying)
        {
            particles.Stop();
            isParticlePlaying = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed my code to this and it works! but could you please tell me why it doesn't play with my other code? you said "Update() loop means every frame so what's happening is your ParticleSystem is getting played every frame so not playing at all" why won't it play?

Comment: See as you are getting direction by 'GetAxis' value this doesn't go well with the 'Update()' method frame timings which caused 'particles.Play()' to able to play due to continuous callbacks but for example instead if you had used 'GetKeyDown' to check for 'TopArrowKey' pressed or not, it would not made issues with the 'Update()' loop. I hope I made it a bit clearer.